# What is wrong with my setup of flutter geolocator: ^6.1.7?

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation

BTW-  Things work as anticipated on IOS.
The trouble I'm having is running on Android (Nexus 5 API 30)

I have carefully followed the [instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) for setup paying special attention to the
gradle.properties and "android/app/build.gradle"  The AndroidManifest.xml  was also updated to include the

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
```

when the app starts, there is prompting asking to allow location services.
[image: Prompt to setup app location services permission]

I can even check that the location services on the app are indeed enabled-[image]

Here is the code that calls geolocation...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }
  void getLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    print(position);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            getLocation();
          },
          child: Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the code there is a very long list of exceptions the first few are:

```
E/flutter (21698): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: The location service on the device is disabled.
E/flutter (21698): #0      MethodChannelGeolocator._handlePlatformException (package:geolocator_platform_interface/src/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:192:9)
E/flutter (21698): #1      MethodChannelGeolocator.getCurrentPosition (package:geolocator_platform_interface/src/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:121:7)
E/flutter (21698): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21698): #2      Geolocator.getCurrentPosition (package:geolocator/geolocator.dart:258:35)
```

Comment: Check whether the device is enabled for location

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
 await getLocation();
} catch(e,s){
 //handle errors
}
```

and some of the Android emulators has this exact problem (bug), try a different emulator, or device

Answer (score 0):

**initialize variable**

```
Position _currentPosition;
```

code

```
_getCurrentLocation() async{
 await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        print(_currentPosition); 
    
      });

    
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

Run `flutter clean` uninstall the app from phone/emulator and restart the phone/emulator
then run the app again after accepting permission it will ask for enable location dialog automatically,if the problem occurs try with [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package

Answer (score 0):

Adding forceAndroidLocationManager:true made it work for me.

```
position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.medium,
              forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
```